# Máscara para input DATA: "00/00/0000" === '0 a 31' / '0 a 12' / '19 || 20' '0 a 9' '0 a 9' =

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

Olá, preciso fazer com que meu `<input id="data">` tenha como parâmetros:
levando em conta o formato de : `00/00/000;`
os dois primeiros de 0 a 31. (caso coloquem  valor acima, ele reseta para 31)
O terceiro: 0 ou 1;
O quarto numero: 0 a 12;

e o quinto e o sexto  apenas: 19 ou 20;
o sétimo e o oitavo números livres de 0 a 9;

```
               // ADICIONANDO METHOD DE DATA NO VALIDATION
    $.validator.addMethod("data",function(value, element) {
    value = jQuery.trim(value);
    var a = value;
    var b = a.charAt(0); // aqui eu ACREDITO ter selecionado o primeiro numero 
    return value.match(/^\d\d?\d\d\/\d\d\d\d$/);
    return this.optional(element) || retorno;
    },
    "Por favor, informe uma data válida"

    );
```

As barras já são inseridas na máscara que criei:
              jQuery(function($){

```
                 $("#data").mask("99/99/9999");
                 $("#fone").mask("(99) 9999-9999");
                 $("#cpf").mask("999.999.999-99");
                 $("#cep").mask("99.999-999");
                  });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9juy4m5j/)
isso usando jquery. :)

Comment: e queres que as barras sejam inseridas pelo usuário ou pela máscara?

Comment: As barras já são inseridas pela máscara, preciso apenas do controle do valor que é inserido

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9juy4m5j/

Comment: o intuito principal é criar uma máscara ou validar a data ou ambos? Se for para validar, pode tentar esse plugin: http://jqueryvalidation.org/date-method/

Comment: o intuito e fazer que o usuário não consiga colocar uma valor acima de 31 nos 2 primeiros caracteres e assim por diante, está explicado lá em cima.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estive quase uma hora de volta desse plugin e achei ele meio limitado.

O plugin tem uma função que é chamada quando o input estiver completo, a solução passa por aí. Primeiro procurei na documentação e código sobre um `evento` com `callback` e nada... depois tentei mudar no evento `keyup` e funciona, mas o plugin guarda um valor interno não publico e repõe o valor guardado apesar de eu fazer `input.value = 'novo valor';` acho isso má prática...

Mas enfim, criticas à parte podes fazer assim:

```
$("#data").mask("99/99/9999", {
    completed: function () {
        console.log('complete')
        var value = $(this).val().split('/');
        var maximos = [31, 12, 2100];
        var novoValor = value.map(function (parcela, i) {
            if (parseInt(parcela, 10) > maximos[i]) return maximos[i];
            return parcela;
        });
        if (novoValor.toString() != value.toString()) $(this).val(novoValor.join('/')).focus();
    }
});
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/10ew5u0x/